# create a class instance as html element

Tags: javascript, html, object

I want to create a dynamic HTML/JS user interface.
For this I will dynamically create objects, which will be represented as a button on my html.
now, I want to track click events of course.
How do I dynamically add an addEventlistener to this special instance of the button?
(each button creates its own svg icon)
My idea is, that the object IS the button, but I am not sure how to do that...

my idea is like following:

```
class Lightbulb {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {String} id
     * @param {boolean} state 
     */
    constructor(id, state){
        this.id = id;
        this.state = state;
        /*
            create the icon here...
        */
        
        //is it somehow possible to achieve the following?
        this.addEventlistener("click", this.setState(!this.state));
    }
    /**
    *
    * {boolean} newState
    */
    setState(newState){
        console.log(newState)
    }

``
```

Comment: You should take a look at [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

Comment: To be honest, that looks like the same principle, doesn't it?
So, yes it does :-D couldn't find it in advance... need to improve my searching skills...

Answer (score 3):

### Use [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

**Real credit to @Guerric P**

I'd never heard of Web Components (in this context) until today. And I've got to say, I whipped up an example based on your code, and the documentation Guerric P provided. Your code was actually really close. I cleaned it up a bit, but it's nearly identical to yours.

Not only does your idea have solid thought behind it, it's actually an HTML5 technology waiting to be implemented.

```js
class Lightbulb extends HTMLElement {
  state = false;
  /**
   * @param {String} id
   */
  constructor(id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;

    this.addEventListener("click", this.toggleState);
  }

  toggleState() {
    this.state = !this.state;
    this.classList.toggle("on", this.state);
  }
}

customElements.define("light-bulb", Lightbulb);
```

```css
light-bulb.on {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<light-bulb>Clickable Lightbulb</light-bulb>
```